# Rx.Observable.range is missing in Typescript

Tags: java, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use RxJS with Typescript and downloaded everything what I need.
Then I wanted to test if the code works:
[image]

As you can see `Rx.Observable.range` the range method is marked as red.

I look into the `Observable.ts` and search for range method, it does not find.

But it exists under the folder observable a `range.ts` file.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error that `.range()` is not defined? Maybe your typings are just old/wrong (depends on your editor).

Comment: This is also happening with Python! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813884/is-there-intellisense-auto-complete-in-visualstudio-for-the-reactive-extension