# Is there Intellisense / auto-complete in VisualStudio for the Reactive Extension rx.py?

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense, rx-py

I'm Visual Studio and I've started a new Python project in a Python 3 environment. Rx has been pip installed and I have the following code

```
from rx import Observable

xs = Observable.range(1, 10)
q = xs.where(lambda x: x % 2 ==0).select(lambda x: -x)

q.subscribe(print)
```

It's runs fine but when I typed `Observable.ran...` I expected to see Intellisense pop up with `range(...)" as an option, as it does normally, but it never did.

Why is this and how can I get Intellisense working for it?

Comment: Hi Robino, could you please share the detail step that you install the Rx? I tried to run the command: pip install rx and the installation is successful, when I typed 'r' after the word 'from' like your example there is no option 'rx' to be select, it looks like I missed something to configure.

Comment: Hi Sara, This sounds like it should be a separate question? 

Anyway, inside Visual Studio, I start a new python project. In solution explorer I right click "Python Environments" and "Add Virtual Environment". Here I select "Python 64-bit 3.6" and call it something like "My Env" and hit Create. Back in the Solution Explorer, right click env and select "Install Python Package" then enter "rx". 

If you ask a question then I can attach pictures for you. Best, Robin

Comment: Related question (but for JavaScript) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38889155/rx-observable-range-is-missing-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks for your description, followed your steps and I met the same issue as yours, since the same issue also existing in JavaScript. It looks like this issue is more relates to Rx and maybe we can go to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY/issues and raise up this issue to the Rx product team to seek for a more professional support.

Comment: Excellent idea Sara, well volunteered!! ;-)